# Magento Post Upgrade steps : 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have recently upgraded magento version from 2.3 to 2.4

WHat are the potential post upgrade steps for further process ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is not fully clear, please try to ask some specific question

There are no post-upgrade steps - the goal of upgrading should be a working system without any additional steps

To upgrade to 2.4 you need

- Install and setup Elasticsearch
- install MariaDB version compatible with Magento 2.4
- Update Magento itself with composer
- Run setup:upgrade command